# Are there any prerequisites / precautions I need to take to make "loading" screen work in Godot?

Tags: loading, game-development, godot, gdscript

I'm new to Godot and I'm working on my first project in that. The previous game was made on Adobe Flash using AS3. While I coded that, I didn't take the best methods to code the project (used a lot of frames and scripts on the frames instead of using external scripts}). Because of that mistake, I couldn't really code a completely functional loading screen in the end. I don't want the same to happen with my Godot game.

**So, what are things I should avoid completely for my loading to work? Also, is setting up a loading screen the last step to game development?**

I've seen these instructions to learn how to make a loading screen - https://godotengine.org/qa/41325/how-to-create-a-loading-screen  Do you suggest I use the same code for my game? Do I load the loading screen scene the first (making it my main scene)?

Answer (score 0):

To have seamless level transition with loading screens you will need to have a Master scene that loads/unloads your child scenes (mainmenu, loadingscreen, level1, level2 etc) as needed.  Flow would be as followings:

- Load MasterScene
- MasterScene loads mainmenu scene as child of itself
- Player selects a level to play
- MasterScene shows a loadingscreen scene as child of itself
- MasterScene loads a level as a child of itself
- When the level is done loading it notifies the MasterScene (parent of the level scene)
- MasterScene shows (makes visible) the level scene
- MasterScene makes the loadingscreen scene non-visible

Hope this helps as a general guide